# How can I make my app repeat this function every minute?

Tags: java, android, function, repeat

I''m currently making an app that displays a digital clock in a random place onCreate. What I want the app to do is just repeat that function every minute. Has anybody got any ideas how this could be implemented?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.digitalClock1);  
    Random r = new Random();

    int x = r.nextInt(350 - 100);
    int y = r.nextInt(800 - 100);

    textView.setX(x);  
    textView.setY(y);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: use asynchronous task in your app

Comment: better do the task in seperate function and call it wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

Use `Handler`

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Random r = new Random();

                int x = r.nextInt(350 - 100);
                int y = r.nextInt(800 - 100);

                textView.setX(x);  
                textView.setY(y);
            }
        }, 1000 * 60);
```

Comment: I keep getting told that you can't update the UI from this thread. People say I need to use AsyncTask. Is this right?

Comment: No, because this Handler run on the UI Looper

Comment: if you create your Handler in the Activity context it's the UI Looper, so you don't need to be worried